# No user save in database with rest restangular.all post

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, rest, restangular

I have a problem to perform a rest post request for saving data in a database .

I created a form register.html and a RegisterCtrl.js controller to add the user account in the database .

The url to create a user is **register** : **http://localhost:8100/#/register**

I use the framework Ionic and AngularJS
Unfortunately, no post application works .
Can you help me.

Thank you.

### Template register.html

```
 <ion-modal-view ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
  <ion-content>
    <form ng-controller="RegisterCtrl">
      <div class="register listRegister">
          <label class="register item item-input">
            <span class="spanLogin icon-left ion-person"></span>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username" />
          </label>

          <label class="register item item-input">
            <span class="spanLogin icon-left ion-email"></span>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email" />
          </label>

          <label class="register item item-input">
            <span class="spanLogin icon-left ion-key"></span>
            <input type="password" class="form-control" ng-model="user.password" placeholder="Password" />
          </label>
      </div>

      <div class="registerButton">
          <button class="validLogin button button-block button-assertive" type="submit">Registration
          </button>  
          <a href="#/home" class="createAccount button button-block button-calm">Back</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </ion-content>
</ion-modal-view>
```

### Controller registerCtrl.js

```
    'use strict'

angular.module('djoro.controllers',['restangular']);

    .controller('RegisterCtrl', function($scope, restangular) {

    var userRegister = {
                "username": user.username,
                "email": user.email,
                "password": user.password
            };

    Restangular.all('register').post(userRegister).then(
                function (data) {
                    $scope.register = data;
                });
});
```

### Api rest by python Django

```
 class UserRegistration(viewsets.ViewSet):
    """
    Called with the URL r'^register/*$'. It allows POST requests.\n
    POST requests allow to create a new user. The parameters to post are 'username','email','password'.\n
    It raises an HTTP 400 error if the POST request is invalid and an HTTP 401 error if an user with the username or email specified already exists.
    """        

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username')
        password = request.data.get('password')
        email=request.data.get('email')
        try :
            user=register(username, email, password)
            user.backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend'
            user.save()
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect("/me/")
        except AttributeError:
            return Response({"detail": "User with this email or username already exists"}, status=HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
```

Comment: And where is the code that should save to the database?

Comment: I just added the code for the API rest by python - Django.
Thank's

Comment: Does your request reach the API? could you dump the request that it gets?